# How does rewriting $x^2 -y^2$ as $(x+y)(x-y)$ avoid catastrophic cancellation?

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, catastrophic-cancellation

Why is rewriting $x^2 -y^2$ as $(x+y)(x-y)$ a way to avoid catastrophic cancellation?

We are still doing $(x-y)$. Is it because the last operation in the second form is a multiplication?

Comment: I don't see how "catastrophic cancellation" could appear. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 16):

$x^2-y^2$ will be only as precise as $x^2$ is. If $x$ and $y$ are close to each other, the computational error might be larger than the result.

In the second case, less loss of significance occurs.

Consider e.g. $x = 9000.2$ and $y = 9000.1$, where the floating-point precision is 5 significant digits. $x^2-y^2$ is actually equal to 1800.03.

Let's try to compute it in $x^2-y^2$ way: $x^2 = 81003600.04 = 81003000$; $y^2 = 81001800.01 = 81001000$, so $x^2-y^2 = 2000$, which is quite far away from the precise answer.

So let's try to compute it in $(x+y)(x-y)$ way: $x+y = 18000.3 = 18000$; $x-y = 0.1$, so $(x+y)(x-y) = 1800$, which is significantly closer to the precise answer (and is actually as close as possible with 5 significant digits).

Comment: But _floating-point_ precision is not measured in digits "after the decimal point"; it is measured in significant digits independently of where the point floats to.

Comment: This all makes sense if by "4 digits after the decimal point", we understand "five significant digits" -- i.e. 4 digits after the decimal point when expressed in the form x.xxxxEnn.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by penartur is correct. His argument works for x and y of order 10^4, which is much less than the 10^16 order at which an overflow error would occur in a double IEEE format. The cancellation really is catastrophic, as the relative error is quite large (in some of my computations it becomes large enough to crash my models).

That being said, if you are dealing with numbers on the order of 10^8, then overflow considerations would start coming into play when trying to compute the squared quantities.

Answer (score -1):

The loss of significant digits is approximately the same for both computations. The second approach will sometimes give you an extra significant digit, but that's not what I would call a catastrophic cancellation.

The real advantage of the second approach is that it avoids unnecessary arithmetic overflow, if $x^2$ and/or $y^2$ exceed the largest representable number. (Or arithmetic underflow, if they are smaller than the smallest representable positive number.)

Comment: Tony's second paragraph is the right answer, methinks.

Comment: No. The answer by @penartur is correct. If x^2 approximately is the same as y^2, and large, you can lose a lot of signficant digits.